# Hide div when page is clicked, unless specific div was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onblur

When the user clicks on `topic_tag_sug` or any of its child elements, that div should not hide. But when the user clicks on any other element, `topic_tag_sug` should hide.

#### HTML

```
<input id='topic_tag' onblur="$('#topic_tag_sug').hide();"/>
<div id='topic_tag_sug' style='border:1px solid #000'>here is tag suggestion zone, i want to click here to select tag suggestion, and it will not be hide</div>​
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#topic_tag').focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7hFw/2/

Comment: What do are you trying to do? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you be a little clearer on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: mmm change "onblur" with "onclick" ?

Comment: i want when we click to topic_tag_sug . the topic_tag_sug will not hide.

Comment: I'm confused????? If you don't want it to hide take out the `onblur="$('#topic_tag_sug').hide();"` Or are you trying to achieve that when the user clicks the topic_tag_sug that the onblur event isn't fired?

Answer (score 1):

I am amusing that you want to hide the suggestion box on some other event. Let's add one close button inside the box itself,

```
<input id='topic_tag' />
<div id='topic_tag_sug' style='border:1px solid #000;display:none;'>
    here is tag suggestion zone, i want to click here to select tag suggestion, and it will not be hide
    <br>
    <a id="close" href="#">X: Close</a>
</div>
```

Now add some javaScript code using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#topic_tag').bind('click', function() {
        $('#topic_tag_sug').show();  
    });    
    $('#close').bind('click', function() {
        $('#topic_tag_sug').hide();
    });        
});
```

Please find working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7hFw/3/)